# Content based routing based on calculated property in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

I need to route a message based on a calculated property/field, but the same attribute/element does not exist in my outgoing schema. Is this possible?

Eg. Suppose I get an inbound message with containing employee name and date of birth. I calculate the age of the employee in orchestration or using functoid in maps. Now I want to send the message based on a condition on age, but the age property does not exist in the outgoing schema.

So Is content based routing possible on calculated properties?

Answer (score 1):

You need a property schema with a property called "Age" and make sure you set this property as "MessageContextPropertyBase" by changing "Property Schema Base" from "Properties" of the node Age. Once you have the property schema then you can promote this property after your calculation either in Orchestration or in a custom receive pipeline component.

1. If you go with an Orchestration approach, then you need to create a correlation type with Age property and initialize the correlation on Send shape. Make sure you also set Age property on your outgoing message with Message_1(...). Deploy the property schema before using it in orchestration. if you are creating it in a different assembly then add a reference to it.
2. Or You can also create a custom pipeline component and promote the same Age property using Promote method in Execute method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that promoted properties need to be part of the message. But you could always create a new message type which imports the original schema but with your new fields included and route based on that. Then you can map back to the original message type on an Outgoing map in your Send Port.

You will of course need to make sure that this new message passes through a pipeline with property promotion such as XMLReceive. So your Orch will need to handle that or alternatively, you could map to this new message in your Receive Port and do your routing before this Orch that you speak of. Difficult to say the best approach with knowing the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can calculate the age and route the inbound message with a local variable.

Comment: You should emphasize more on **how** the routing can be done to improve your answer.